# How to visualize arbitrary arity predicates (ternary, quaternary…)?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Consider language $\mathcal{L}$ with three predicate symbols $P^1$, $R^2$ and $S^3$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model with universe $M = \{a, b, c\}$ and predicates realized as $P^1_\mathcal{M} = \{a, b\}$, $R^2_{\mathcal{M}} = \{(a, b), (a, c), (c, c)\}$ and $S^3_{\mathcal{M}} = \{(a, b, c)\}$. Part of this model can be visualized as (omitting ternary relations):

[image]

Notice that unary predicates are point and binary predicates are arrows. How can I extend this image to represent ternary predicate $S^3$, or even higher arity ones?

Comment: You might draw a *path* of length $2$ (with another color) $a\to b\to c$ to represent $(a, b, c) \in S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Existential Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_graph#Beta) your world would be represented like so:

[image]

Effectively, Peirce chose to use the nodes for predicates/relationships, and lines for objects: just the opposite of what you are doing. However, lines can split, but as long as it is all connected, it is still the same object. Also, a line itself is just an object, and it is only when a line is connected to a constant like '$a$', that we know that this object is denoted by '$a$'.

For predicates, the rule is that the first argument comes at the predicate from theleft, the second on the right, and the third at the bottom. I assume that Peirce (the inventor of Existential Graphs over 100 years ago) would place the fourth at the top ... but I don't know if he ever discussed relations with an arity greater than $4$. One big thing he did stress was that all relations can always be captured by a bunch of $3$-place relations, so maybe that was his way out of this predicament :)

Another option would be to have a predicate represented as $R(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,...)$, where the $\cdots$ are the 'hooks' to which you can attach lines, and where the order is now pretty straightforward.

Or: lay out some convention that says: the first one goes on the left, and the next ones go in clock-wise order. So, you can still do this purely graphically.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Bram28's answer, if we represent the argument number as a special symbol at each end of the line, we can reorganize the graph to be easier to read:

[image]

Here's a hand written version, because I think it looks prettier:

[image]

Comment: That's cool!  Did you ever prove that equivalence?